# Use Windows laptop as external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I know its trivial to use your laptop as a 2nd monitor if your desktop is also running Windows.

But what if you are running Linux(Ubuntu) on your desktop.

Is is still possible to somehow use your laptop as an external monitor?

Comment: You're think of remote access which isn't the same as using the laptop as a second monitor. The remote access is as trivial in Linux or Windows or any combination and often what the exact same software tools. The answer you got is about what you actually asked (sort of) but definitely not about what you meant.

Comment: Windows 10 can accept miracast connection(project to this PC function).  Maybe he is asking if Linux can support miracast.